# I'm trying to create 5 different div elements using this loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I'm trying to create 5 different audio players from the following code to call them out individually wherever I need it in the HTML document: https://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/ZbxYYG

The issue is that this 2 loops use a single div element to call the function:

**For audio:**

```
/* createAudioElements
 * create audio elements for each file in files */
function createAudioElements() {
    for (f in files) {
        var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";
        $("#audio-players").append(audioString);
    }
}
```

**For div element:**

```
/* createAudioPlayers
 * create audio players for each file in files */
function createAudioPlayers() {
    for (f in files) {
        var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
        $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
    }
}
```

But what I'm trying to do is to create **5 different elements to tickle them all individually and call them wherever I need it** in the website with div id="audio-players1", div id="audio-players2", etc.

I've tried to do this for both loops:

Instead of

```
$("#audio-players")
```

Add this:

```
$("#audio-players" + f)
```

But then the buttons won't work.

Here's the code to pull the files from:

```
var files = ["interlude.mp3", // 0
            "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
            "interlude.mp3", // 2
            "scriptures.mp3",
       "scriptures.mp3"// 3
            ];
```

And I'm unsure how to proceed, I'm still learning. **Thank you.**

Comment: where is your button click code

Comment: Essence of JS are pure functions - pass ```files``` variable as function argument: ```function createAudioPlayers(files){}``` and call it multiple times. Note, that when you type ```for (f in files)``` you creates global variable ```f``` - you should add ```let``` or ```var``` keyword before ```f```.

Comment: code above is good it depends on how your those button click events are handled and what selector you are using for them..your for loop is creating separate div for them

Comment: @reski Thank you for replying. I tried to do so but no result. The player doesn't even show up.

Comment: @sumeetkumar I improved the explanation of the issue. 

The button is the following:

 this.timeline.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick, false);
 this.playbutton.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay, false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/KyXjvQ) of what you're looking for.

Changes compared to your code:

1. Re-ordered div and audio creation:

   ```
   createAudioPlayers();  
   createAudioElements();
   ```
2. As you need something like #audio-players2, just tweaked this code a bit:

   ```
   for (f in files) {
       var playerString = "<div id=\"audio-players-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
       $("body").append(playerString);
   }
   ```
3. In the function `createAudioElements()`, append audio based on the audio-player (DIV) ID:

   ```
   $("#audio-players-"+f).append(audioString);
   ```

**Edit:**

New [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/KyXjvQ). I think I figured out the issue here. So when you try to add the players separately, the buttons wouldn't work **BUT** when they were added on the go while creation, all worked fine, right?

So here's the thing: `bindAudioPlayer` wasn't finding the correct element on adding a player separately to the DOM as well as the `timeline` and other elements.

In the new codepen, I've added a button with a select option, which when selected adds a particular player (based on the value) to the DOM. Check the onClick code:

```
  $('a.add_player').click(function() {
      var val = $(this).parent().find('select.player_num').val();
      if(!$('body div#audio-players'+val).length) {
         var playerString = "<div id=\"audio-players" + val + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + val + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + val + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + val + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div><audio id=\"audio-" + val + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/" + files[val-1] + "\"></audio></div>";
         $("body").append(playerString);

        // Populate Audio List
         populateAudioList(val);
         populateComponentDictionary(val);
      }
  });
```

If you can also check the `populateAudioList` function, in which the loop is gotten rid of and the passed value is used to select the DOM element and accordingly events are bound to the selector.

Let me know if this is the desired output. Hope this helps. :)

**Edit 2**

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/NwwLwL)

I've added a function named `createAudioPlayersSeparately()` which, I think, fulfils the requirement.

> If you notice, I've swapped files for player 3 and player 4 i.e. used file 4 for player 3 and file 3 for player 4. Now, that means, it should be easy enough to call any player with any audio "wherever" you'd like on the page. Just make sure you call `populateAudioList()` and `populateComponentDictionary()` accordingly.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying, but what I'm trying to do is calling out a single player  wherever I need it in the HTML.

For example:

    <div id="audio-players-1"></div> 

Would call out a single player with a specific song somewhere in the document and 

<div id="audio-players-2"></div> would do the same. But right now they're being called out all at once.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean by "would call out a single player". Could you please elaborate? Is that based on some condition?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanations.

Right now when I use <div id="audio-players"></div> in my html document, I receive 5 different audio players by using a single tag.

Instead, my idea is to use <div id="audio-players1"></div>, (where 1 is a specific player with a specific song that I want to invoke, only one player instead of 5).

Comment: Isn't that how it is now? I mean, if you check the DOM elements, every <div id="audio-players<id>"></div> has its own audio within it. Even better is the new edit. (I've added comments in the createAudioPlayer function). Check out the [codepen](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/KyXjvQ) Let me know if I'm still not getting it.

Comment: And if you don't want them all together to be added to the DOM, just take them out of the loop and add them individually wherever you need. (the "playerString" is what you need)

Comment: Yes, it's almost like that, thank you. But I want to invoke them separately in the html document by using <div id="audio-players<id>"></div>.

In your code, it invokes all of them at once in body with different id's but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Damn. That's a great work. I'm sorry but I think that I don't know how to explain myself well. It's almost like what you did, maybe this can help: https://puu.sh/ynCqR/3cb9be0389.png.

What you did is pretty close but I'm trying to use separate <divs> for each player just like in the photo, without a selector.

Thank you a lot, you're amazing!

Comment: Gotcha. Hope the new [link](https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/NwwLwL) works. Check the edit and do not miss the highlighted text. And btw, thanks. :)